# Extract regex with special character

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I want to create a column in a pandas dataframe `df` based on another column `ID`. For `ID` that contains the the string `SAT`, I would like to extract the floats joined by the special character "-" and put the extracted in a new column named `new_col`. If `ID` does not contain the `SAT` string, leave it as `NaN`.

`df` is as below:

```
    Date        ID                   Time
0   2007-01-10  SAT 1 HHSP           900
1   2007-01-10  DOUBLE 7 HHSP        900
2   2007-01-10  SAT GF-06-5CSBG.431  1000
3   2007-01-10  MA HYDRO HHSP        900
4   2007-01-10  2.233 HHSP           900
5   2007-01-10  SAT L2-15-3CSB1.252  1000
6   2007-01-10  SECTION 6 HHSP       900
```

Expected output:

```
    Date        ID                   Time     new_col
0   2007-01-10  SAT 1 HHSP           900      NaN
1   2007-01-10  DOUBLE 7 HHSP        900      NaN
2   2007-01-10  SAT GF-06-5CSBG.431  1000     06-5
3   2007-01-10  MA HYDRO HHSP        900      NaN
4   2007-01-10  2.233 HHSP           900      NaN
5   2007-01-10  SAT L2-15-3 CSB1.252  1000    15-3  * In this case 15-3 instead of 2-15 is extracted because L2 is not completely floats.
6   2007-01-10  SECTION 6 HHSP       900      NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with numbers joined by `-` with `-` before it and only for values with `SAT` filtered by [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
m = df['ID'].str.contains('SAT')
df['new_col'] = df.loc[m, 'ID'].str.extract('[-\s+](\d+\-\d+)')
print (df)
         Date                   ID  Time new_col
0  2007-01-10           SAT 1 HHSP   900     NaN
1  2007-01-10        DOUBLE 7 HHSP   900     NaN
2  2007-01-10  SAT GF-06-5CSBG.431  1000    06-5
3  2007-01-10        MA HYDRO HHSP   900     NaN
4  2007-01-10           2.233 HHSP   900     NaN
5  2007-01-10  SAT L2-15-3CSB1.252  1000    15-3
6  2007-01-10       SECTION 6 HHSP   900     NaN
```

If value `SAT` start in column is possible use:

```
df['new_col'] = df['ID'].str.extract('^SAT.*[-\s+](\d+\-\d+)', expand=False)
```

Comment: Hi jezrael, thank you for your answer, `ID` `SATGF 06-3 CSB G-407` returned `NaN` while I expected it to return `06-03` since there are 2 floats joined by a `-` character. Is it because there are 2 `-`?

Comment: @nilsinelabore - then use `df.loc[m, 'ID'].str.extract('[-\s+](\d+\-\d+)')` - test space or `-` before `INT-INT` numbers